# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'all'

Tags: php

I'm working on a PHP webpage, and I get an error on my front-end saying; `Warning: Illegal string offset 'all' on line 93.`

Here's the code on line 93;

```php
$all_categories = isset($options['categories']) && $options['categories']['all'] ? true : false;
```

Comment: `$options['categories']` is a string, not a multidimensional array. Var_dump it and see what the output is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that while

```
$options['categories']
```

is valid

```
$options['categories']['all']
```

is not.

Changing your line to

```
$all_categories = isset($options['categories']) && 
                  isset($options['categories']['all']) && 
                  $options['categories']['all'] ? true : false;
```

Will suppress your error and return FALSE.  (linefeeds added for clarity only and can be removed)

Comment: Thanks; how did @RiggsFolly's code "$all_categories = isset($options['categories'],$options['categories']['all']) ? true : false;" seem to solve my error though?

Comment: It is explained in the answer... you were only checking for one of the two required values (nested arrays) The outer array was there $options['categories'] but the inner was not $options['categories']['all'] - you need to check for both.  Adding the second check accomplished that.  The other answer is using an internal function that accomplishes both.  If you were to look at the compiled result of the two I would wager that they would be pretty identical.  My version is more explicit and would be clearer to support programmers - his is tighter and results in denser code - it's a style choice

Comment: Good article explaining the nuances between undefined/null/false as values and how the various functions treat them https://www.codepunker.com/blog/is-null-vs-empty-vs-isset-one-lesson-all-php-coders-should-learn

Comment: ok, so in this case; `<?php if ( $active_tabs['latest'] ) { ?><li class="active"><a href="#latest-posts-<?php echo $id; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><?php _e('Latest', 'radium'); ?></a></li><?php } ?>` that returns an illegal string offset on `<?php if ( $active_tabs['latest'] ) { ?>` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to see if `$options['categories']['all']` exists and has something in it, the code can be simplified to:

```
$all_categories = !empty($options['categories']['all']);
```

You don't need to check if `$options['categories']` is set, because if
 `$options['categories']['all']` is set, then the array that contains it must be set. And a ternary that returns `true` for the true part and `false` for the false part adds unnecessary complexity. The expression before the `?` already gives you the boolean value you need.